# Emulator: emulator: ERROR: Not enough space to create userdata partition (Ubuntu 20.04)

Tags: linux, android-emulator, android-studio

I've been getting the error:

**emulator:  ERROR: Not enough space to create userdata partition. Available: 6910.351562 MB at /home/codedoor/.android/avd/Pixel_4_API_29.avd, need 7372.800000 MB**

I'm running Ubuntu 20.04.  Not sure if it's connected, but Android Studio was working perfectly fine until I updated Node and then the emulator would not run.

I've tried looking for a solution on various platforms, but none have worked so far.  So I completely uninstalled and re-installed it, including deleting related hidden files/directories.  I wiped the data using the AVD manager.

I tried:`emulator -avd Pixel_4_API_29 -partition-size 1024 -wipe-data`  &
`emulator -avd Pixel_4_API_29 -partition-size 7373 -wipe-data`
Both of which caused the same error. I've also checked to see that virtualization was still enabled.

Possible solution: how could I increase storage for Android emulator?  I've tried looking at Android Studio and its configurations, but this has eluded me.

Of course, any other solutions would be helpful as well.

Any help would be *greatly* appreciated.

Happy New Year, btw!  :)

Comment: The error sounds more like you don't have enough free space on your Linux (user) partition check free space via `df -h`. Alternatively this is caused by a permission problem. Check if you can create a file in `home/codedoor/.android/avd/`